# What does this Elon Musk sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

i'm confused about **super tight** meaning in this sentence..

Elon Musk emails Tesla employees: ‘Breaking even is looking **super tight**’

1. breaking even is looking **very close**?
2. reaching to the break even point is **so hard**?

or something else?

Comment: I think he means that they are very close to breaking even.

Comment: this is the link to the reference of this sentence: https://www.cnbc.com/2020/06/29/elon-musk-emails-tesla-workers-breaking-even-is-looking-super-tight.html

Comment: Super = very; tight = difficult or hard to achieve (especially because of disadvantageous circumstances, often beyond one's control)

Comment: Yes, I read the article. He is a great motivator...he would never say that something is super difficult!!

Comment: @user121863 Why wouldn't he say something is super difficult? "Getting to space is super difficult but we did it" could easily be a thing he would say.

Comment: It is [touch-and-go](https://www.lexico.com/definition/touch-and-go) whether they will break even. In other words, it is quite possible that they won't meet their production target, or their accounts will show a loss (which, the article says, is unclear).

Comment: What is an elon musk?

Answer (score 1):

I read the sentence "Breaking even is looking super tight" as "The margin of error in order to break even is small".  It means that the profits of the business venture are very close to exceeding the costs given the current trajectory, but there is still a chance to break even.

Some other usages where the meaning is similar:

- I was parking my car in the garage and almost hit the door frame.  It was a **super tight** fit.
- I have a test in the morning but I haven't started studying.  It will be **super tight**, but I think if I start studying now I can still make it in time.